# How to access router.asPath in a function that uses next/navigation in the Next.js app directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";


const router = useRouter()

const refreshData = () => {
router.replace(router.asPath);
```

}

i tried using next/router but didn't worked

Comment: If you are not using the new `app` folder, why not using `import { useRouter } from 'next/router'`?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar you cannot, per docs, app dir needs to import from `next/navigation`. See: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#step-5-migrating-routing-hooks

Comment: Yeah which is why I said "if you are not using the new `app` folder" @brandonscript :)

Comment: @YoussoufOumar OH silly me, I misread that. You're right, looks like OP is not using app dir, despite my finding this question from an edit queue that updated the title to show that 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Next.js 13's new app directory scheme, `useRouter` doesn't work the same way. You will want `usePathname` instead: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#step-5-migrating-routing-hooks

Worth noting that there is also an [open issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42016#discussioncomment-4847318) where in certain circumstances, `useRouter` and `usePathname` don't work as expected (particularly around router.events).

But also as @YoussoufOumar has pointed out, it doesn't look like you're using app dir, so you want to import from `next/router`.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use **usePathname**

```
'use client'
 
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  return <p>Current pathname: {pathname}</p>
}
```